# QRegularExpression multiline does not match newline

Tags: regex, qt

I need to match the two line between the text --BB0 and --EE0 so I use this regular expression in QT:

```
QRegularExpression rx0("(--BB0\n)(.*)(\n.*--EE0)", QRegularExpression::MultilineOption | QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption)
```

This regular expression correctly matches in this case

```
QRegularExpressionMatch match = rx0.match("    --BB0\n    AAAA\n    BBBB\n    --EE0");
```

but it doesn't find anything when I match on the actual string that is

```
--BB0
signal our_ip_address      : std_logic_vector (31 downto 0)  :=   x"c0a80509" ;   -- 192.168.5.9
signal our_mac_address     : std_logic_vector (47 downto 0)  :=   x"002320212223";
--EE0
```

where am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You don't need all of this, just use the following expression:

```
--BB0(.*?)--EE0
```

and use the `QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption`, you don't need the `QRegularExpression::MultilineOption` because you are not using `^` or `$` in your regular expression.

The match will be captured in group 1.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rQ1bU8)

Comment: So why was multiline not working, then? How would the OP get those Qt pattern options working?